# How can I prevent rarely used TCP sessions from being dropped

Tags: windows, networking, tcp, router

I have an application that relies on maintaing some open TCP sessions.
These have low usage, about used once every 5 minutes or so.

My router drops unused TCP sessions after a timeout of 2 minutes. The application does not handle this correctly and crashes.

I can updated my router settings to increase this timeout setting to over 5 minutes and everything works ok.

I know the application could send periodic ping messages to prevent TCP sessions as being marked as unused. Or it could use keepalive settings on the connection and Windows would send TCP keepalives. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the application source code and cannot do this.

I want a solution that does not rely on changing the router settings or application settings.

One solution is to use a VPN, in this case the the TCP connection is active even if the underlying connection isn't being used. My router won't disconnect it. I would prefer not to have to do this.

Solution 2 might be some sort of TCP proxy that would relay TCP requests but tack-on some keepalives. Would this work? Any specific tools for this?

Or is there any other simple solution? OS is Windows.

Comment: "_The application does not handle this correctly and crashes._" Fix that in any case. Also, configure the router to have a longer timeout. You can also set up a keepalive. "_Unfortunately, I do not have access to the application source code and cannot do this._" I do not know how programmers can help you fix an application with no access to the application.

Comment: Your question is very hard to answer because you suggest a perfect answer (using a VPN) and then say you'd prefer not to do it but don't explain why. Without knowing why you don't want to use the simple, obvious solution, your question is unanswerable. You must be rejecting a VPN because you have some unstated requirements and without knowing the requirements, how can we suggest a solution? It would be a waste of time for me to detail a solution for you to just think, "that's no better than a VPN", when I have no idea what criteria you are using to compare.

Comment: @EoinH Can you put a proxy on both ends? Do you understand the application protocol?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks for the response. I'm looking at a temporary workaround without any additional costs for users. That's the main requirement. Apart from the cost, the VPN solution seems to me to be a bit heavy-handed. I was hoping for a solution like some TCP proxy that could run targetting specific ports or targetting the specific application. Or maybe some global setting on Windows to set keepalives for all connections. If a VPN is the only solution though, I'll go with that.

Comment: I don't know anything about the application protocal. I just see on wireshark there are TCP resets and retransmissions after a certain time that go away when I increase the session timeout on my router. Thats all I know

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't fully understand what you mean. I have access to the client application and not the server. I was thinking I'd just need a proxy between the client application and my router. By "proxy on both ends", do you mean I'd need a further proxy between server and my router? If thats case, I don't have access. I didn't think about that but I would have expected only the client would start sessions. I don't know though and my TCP knowledge isn't great.

Comment: @EoinH So you don't have the application software, don't understand or have any decumentation of the protocol, don't have any access to, or control over, the server,  and you don't control the client machines or administer their networks? Why is this your problem? What's in scope for your role exactly? What is your relationship to the application exactly?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm just a user. I need to use this application. I have a simple workaround (using VPN) for the moment. I'm looking for a better workaround. I do control the client machine.

Comment: @EoinH Then I would start by contacting the developer of the application. You have proof the application has a bug that impacts your ability to use it. They may have an updated version or bugfix. The most obvious solution is to work with someone who has the ability to solve it properly.